# Text Progress bar (Email)

Tags: html, css, email, text, progress-bar

I am currently developing a template email and I'have developed this :

```html
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#f83f83" style="width:50%; background-color:#f83f83; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#cccccc" style="width:50%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But i would like the dynamic percentage Indicated in the center of the progress bar. 
do you have a solution to make it compatible with the email client that are quite capricious ?

Thanks

Comment: An image ? but the percentage is dynamic, I will not create images of 0-100

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to exactly centre text over that progress bar, because you can't really put anything *on top of* that table - `position:absolute;` won't work on most email clients.

However, you could try something like:

```html
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#f83f83" style="width:50%; background-color:#f83f83; float:left; height:15px;text-align:right;">5</td>
  <td bgcolor="#cccccc" style="width:50%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;text-align:left;">0%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This would mean that the percentage is always over the current location of the progress bar, for example:

```html
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#f83f83" style="width:35%; background-color:#f83f83; float:left; height:15px;text-align:right;">3</td>
  <td bgcolor="#cccccc" style="width:65%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;text-align:left;">5%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh it's a good solution but but I wish it was not in the center and the intersection of the two " td ". It's possible ? ...